# Format Sting is not a string literal on [[self navigationController] setToolbarHidden:YES];

Tags: objective-c, ios

Can someone please tell me why I am receiving a "Format string is not a string literal (potentially insecure)" warning on

```
[[self navigationController] setToolbarHidden:YES];
```

It is driving me crazy.

Comment: I can't see how it comes from that line of code. That message would come from a method call such as `stringWithFormat:` or NSLog where you pass in a string variable instead of a string literal for the format string.

Comment: Also, you're abusing the 'Xcode' tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning doesn't seem related to the code at all. Try cleaning, building or analyzing the project; anything that would cause an error check again. It's probably an old error from a different line.